# kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly icloud restore vs transfer directly from iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

When i transfer data from one phone to another, Values present in keychain are getting erased when i restore data via icloud, but when i use the transfer directly from iphone, keychain values are not getting erased. I have set accessibilityType for keychain as kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly but still it is not working when i use "transfer directly from iphone" during iphone restore. Any idea why? is it because it is deprecated? will kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly behave the same way?

Answer (score 0):

“ThisDeviceOnly” means a keychain item will be only accessible on that particular device. It won’t be available for example if you backup your app and restore on a different iPhone.

As a developer, you need to be aware of this, and expect these values to be not present suddenly and make it possible for the user to recreate these things. Things the user can’t recreate must be stored with different flags.